# Azure AD: How to get both security groups and application roles into access token

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, access-token, azure-api-apps

I am facing a scenario where my .NET Core app (Azure Web API) will be accessed in two ways:

- **client_credentials flow**
- **delegated permissions (user) flow**

I am using **Microsoft Identity Web** to authorize and authenticate requests via AD on middleware level. Then I would like to do additional authorization inside my controller methods to check the following:

1. In case of **application call (client credentials)**, check that the provided **access_token** contains a specific roles claim that matches with the application role defined in **app registrations** -> **app roles**.
2. In case of **signed-in user call**, check that the provided **access_token** contains specific AD Groups (security groups) assigned to that user in Azure AD.

Flow #1 works, but if I enable flow #2 by clicking on **token configuration -> add groups claim -> Security Groups -> emit groups as role claims in access token**, then the app roles are no longer available in the client credentials flow inside the access token (as in the below screenshot), presumably because it overwrites the roles claim with the security groups (which do not exist for applications).

**What is the correct way to do this, or achieve an equivalent situation in a different way?**
The requirement is to differentiate controller method access where application A can call e.g. a read-only endpoint 1, but cannot call write endpoint 2, whereas application B is able to call write endpoint 2. The same differentiation should be done also for users on AD-group basis.

[image: access_token]

Answer (score 0):

You can [include a `groups` claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes) in your token. You just need to modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

Then the token will contain the Ids of the groups that the use belongs to like below :

```
{
  "groups": ["{group_id}"]
}
```

This method won't overwrite the `roles` claim. So for delegated permissions (user) flow, you need to check the `groups` claim instead now.

Comment: Configuring it in this manner, I no longer see the app roles in the Roles claim. It will display the security groups now in groups as you suggest, but not the app roles. Any thoughts?

Comment: @PetteriPertola Based on my test, the delegated user access token includes the `groups` claim and the application access token includes the app roles in `roles` claim. Make sure that you check the app roles in application access token rather than delegated user access token. If the issue still exists, please share how you define the app role and how you acquire the application access token.

Comment: @PetteriPertola Did you check my comment? Any updates?

Comment: Sorry - easter vacation. I was able to find an alternative which was to assign the applications into the security groups in AD as service principals, and in this case I get the AD group object IDs in the roles claim. This way we only require a single way of authorization regardless of whether you are a user or an application, so this solution worked for us in the end.